# Could not copy the file "resources.dll" because it was not found

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm getting this error after clicked for the first time in `TEST-> Debug -> All Tests`

I've been looking and seen something to add Pre build events but it didn't worked out, the error code:

> Error   1   Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\qps-ploc\Bigbuilder.resources.dll" because it was not found. Bigbuilder

The program doesn't debug at the first try but when it asks "there was build errors. Would you like to run the last successfull build?" if i click no and retry to execute it will say nothing but the error will mantain in the error list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall the Multilingual App Toolkit from Programs and Features, download the latest version, and re-install. This fixes the build issues.

Encountered the same problem with building a console application using the Multilingual App Toolkit in a Portable Class Library, and now it is working.